# Edge Detection using PyOpenCL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, opencl, pyopencl

I was having an issue while writing a python script to detect the edge using PyOpenCl. I am new to OpenCL and while trying I encountered a problem which after many tweaks, I am unable to solve. below is the python code:

edge.py:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
from PIL import Image
from time import time


def getKernel(krnl):
    kernel = open(krnl).read()
    return kernel


def findedges(p,d,image):

    data = np.asarray(image).astype(np.uint8)

    platform = cl.get_platforms()[p]
    device = platform.get_devices()[d]
    cntx = cl.Context([device])
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(cntx)

    mf = cl.mem_flags
    im = cl.Buffer(cntx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=data)
    out = cl.Buffer(cntx,mf.WRITE_ONLY,data.nbytes)

    prgm = cl.Program(cntx,getKernel('edge.c')%(data.shape[1],data.shape[0])).build()

    prgm.detectedge(queue,data.shape,None,im,out)

    result = np.empty_like(data)

    cl.enqueue_copy(queue,result,out)
    result = result.astype(np.uint8)
    print(result)

    img = Image.fromarray(result)
    #img.show()
    img.save('coinsedge.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = Image.open('coins.png')
    #(1,0) is my platform 1, device 0 = "AMD gpu"  
    #(0,0) for intel processor 
    findedges(1,0,image)
```

and my kernel file : edge.c

```c
__kernel void detectedge(__global int *im,__global int *out){
      int j = get_global_id(1);
      int i = get_global_id(0);
      int width = %d;
      int rown = %d;
      int value;


              value = -im[(i)*width + j] -  0* im[(i)*width + j+1] + im[(i)*width + j+2]
                      -2*im[(i+1)*width + j] +  0*im[(i+1)*width + j+1] + 2*im[(i+1)*width + j+2]
                      -im[(i+2)*width + j] -  0*im[(i+2)*width + j+1] + im[(i+2)*width + j+2];

              value = (value < 0   ? 0   : value);
              value = (value > 255 ? 255 : value);
              out[i*width + j] = value;

  }
```

Now there are no run-time warnings/errors but the output is what I was not expecting. Here is the input and its output: 
This is my input image:

[image: input]

And this is my output:

[image: output]

Comment: I don't know OpenCL at all but I believe you are maybe passing 8-bit integer pixels to OpenCL but telling it they are 32-bit integers. Does it produce same result on CPU as GPU?

Comment: yeah... on all the platforms...the result is same... i even tried to change `uint8` to `int` and tried if condition like : `if(i<=row-2 && j<= width-2)` but the result is the same !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the size of the input and output buffers you are passing to the kernel. The image is one `uint8` per pixel and you sized your buffer according to `data.nbytes`. The kernel is reading and writing 4 byte pixels.

I only had to change this line and it works:

```
data = np.asarray(image).astype(np.int32)
```

[image]

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot ! though i managed to rewrite the kernel from _OpenCL Parallel Programming Development Cookbook -- Chapter 6_ ... but it showed horizontal lines ... however i guess i should stick with my own kernel.

Comment: Just rotate the multiplying coefficients in your kernel round by 90 degrees.